# doctrine schema create couldnt find constant

Tags: php, orm, symfony, doctrine-orm, schema

Im getting the following error:

> "Semantical Error" Couldn't find constant inverseJoinColumns, property Test\NewsBundle\Entity\Post::$tags.

When trying to generate schema using doctrine, any help is appreciated thanks.

```
    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
    * @ORM\JoinTable(name="post_tag",
    *   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="postID", referencedColumnName="id")},
    *   inverseJoinColumns{@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tagID", referencedColumnName="id")}
    * )
    * 
    * @var ArrayCollection $tags
    */
    protected $tags;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an equal sign:

```
inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tagID", referencedColumnName="id")}
```

Comment: thank you, spose this is what i get for trying to write stuff at 1am lol